# Fortify-scanner : Password Management: Password in Configuration File

Tags: spring-boot, fortify

Fortify scan reports this property in spring-boot application.properties as high issue as it assumes password in plain text.
Below code reads the password from environment variable.I have environment variables(DB_PASSWORD) in kubernetes cluster.so I need to have this property in spring-boot application.

can anyone provide any other alternatives?

```
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD:}
```